# How are U.S. Congress bills assigned their number?

Tags: united-states, congress

We are currently in the 115th U.S. Congress that started in January of 2017.

How is it that the [Tax Cuts and Jobs Act](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/1) is assigned #1 in its bill name (H.R. 1) when it wasn't introduced until 9 months after this congress began?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_(law)) (emphasis mine)

> Every two years, at the start of odd-numbered years, the United States Congress recommences numbering from 1, **though for bills the House has an order reserving the first 20 bill numbers** and the Senate has similar measures for the first 10 bills.

So this bill was given a special number for the purposes of recording.

Per the [Congressional website](https://www.congress.gov/help/legislative-glossary/#glossary_reservedbillnumbers)

> In recent Congresses, the resolution specifying House internal rules of procedure includes reserving bill numbers for assignment by the Speaker. In the 112th Congress (2011-2012) the practice was extended to reserve additional bill numbers for assignment by the Minority Leader.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I couldn't track down the original source [6] of the statement. But I'm assuming it is correct.

Comment: @AdamJohns [Here's an official source](https://www.congress.gov/help/legislative-glossary/#glossary_reservedbillnumbers)